# error TS2339: Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

Trying to upgrade from angular 5.2 to angular 6.0.0, we are running into the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<
```

Any ideas why?

The Code where we are using is

```
return this.httpClient.post<x>(`${environment.apiUrl}auth/x/`,
  this.abcd,
  httpOptions)
  .do(x1 => this.subject.next(x1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain operators were deprecated a while back and now they're removed. Use pipeable operators, in this case `tap` replaces `do`.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.httpClient.post(ˋ${environment.apiUrl}auth/x/ˋ, this.abcd, httpOptions)
.pipe(
    tap(x1 => this.subject.next(x1))
);
```